# Lazy loading with Angular 6.1, error with ng build

Tags: javascript, django, angular, angular-router

I have a Angular 6.1 application which is served by django. When I try to `ng build` this and open it, following error is occuring:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk recordmanagement-records-module-ngfactory failed.
```

There is no import of the records-module or its component in the app-module.
If I `ng serve` this, it works just fine. I also tried `--aot` and a custom webpack build with angular-router-loader, which didn't work.

This is the app-routing:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "records", loadChildren: './recordmanagement/records.module#RecordsModule'},
    { path: "", pathMatch: "full" , component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And the records-routing:

```
const recordsRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: "",
    component: RecordsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
}];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(recordsRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [AuthGuardService]
})
export class RecordsRoutingModule {}
```

The basic angular depencies are used + ngrx for state management. 
Everything gets built perfectly:

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 233 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 228 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {recordmanagement-records-module-ngfactory} recordmanagement-records-module-ngfactory.js, recordmanagement-records-module-ngfactory.js.map (recordmanagement-records-module-ngfactory) 208 kB  [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 9.09 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 78.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.22 MB [initial] [rendered]
```

Django really just serves the files which are created in the building process.

Do you have any ideas whats happening here?

Comment: loading chunk failed means that the file was not returned from the get call. Try to load the file first. Hit the server using something like this:  
`servername.com/directory/somechunk.chunk.js`. If this does not return a file means there is some issue with server side code

Answer (score 0):

For lazy-loading modules, we need to use `.forchild` method of `RouterModule`.

```
RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers, the problem was indeed not the `.forChild`, I had that already.
but the serving from django, which didnt find the chunk.

solution: 
user `ng build --deploy-url /static/dist/` where '/static/dist/' is the location where the files get compiled.